# removing clicks from singer exceeding microphone range in audacity

Tags: audio, audacity

So my wife recorded a song on her phone. And during the loud part of the song, she exceeded the microphone's ability to record. Now, I just learned I could zoom in really close to the nodes in song and even out the clicks. But it seems to me there has to be a better way.  Here's the wav form:

[image]

I'm not even sure what this is called or what effect I need to apply to smooth out the wav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is called *clipping*.

You can try the Repair function under the Effects menu, but it won't work over a span of I think more than 128 samples.  You will basically have to laboriously do this for each error in the wave and the results may not be great.

The better thing to do is re-record at a lower volume where the clipping doesn't happen, apply the Compressor effect if you have too much difference between the loud and soft parts of the voice, then amplify until you get to the volume you want.  You can always raise the volume if it's too soft, but clipping permanently damages the recording.

Comment: This is one voice among many. Fortunately, this voice is my wife's, so she'll be willing to re-record it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's not clipping*, it's *inverting*. It ran out of 'numbers' at the top, so it rolled them over & put them at the 'bottom'.

This would be laborious but you couple potentially reduce the level of the entire track by the maximum amout of the inversion, then manually move each of those inverted segments back to the 'top' I have not the faintest clue how you would actually achieve that in audacity, as I've never used it, but… there's your 'starter for ten'.

As I don't know Audacity at all, this is a guess - once you have reduced the overall track levels,  you need to find some way of block-selecting each 'broken' segment at exactly the points it crosses over to negative & then manually dragging it to the positive until it lines up perfectly with the correct data. Laborious but not impossible & the end result may be un-noticeable.
You may get lucky & discover they have all been shifted by exactly the same about, so you might be able to multi-select & fix them in one drag. [2 drags, you would have to do the inverse for the ones that are flipped at the negative end - I only see one in that example pic [which also makes me think the original recording has some bad DC offset… but that's a lesson for another day I think]

*If it was clipping, all the data that went above the maximum volume would have become a simple flat line at the top. This would have been irrecoverable, as the data would be gone completely. You could attempt to redraw it by hand, but you would be guessing at what the waveform used to be. 
Because instead is has inverted, your data is there… just at the wrong end of the display.

[I have intentionally used nothing too technical in this explanation. I don't think it's needed to fix the issue.]

Comment: Perhaps this will work, then?
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_click_and_pop_removal_techniques.html

Comment: You'll have to try it & see. I've never used Audacity.